Can't change the color of the xAxis value in tooltip with a composed line chart
I'm trying to change the color of the text inside the tooltip. But nothing seems to work.
Here is my chart:
<ResponsiveChartContainer
        sx={{
          cursor: 'pointer',
          '& .MuiAreaElement-series-price': {
            fill: palette.primary.dark,
            opacity: 0.4
          }
        }}
        xAxis={[
          {
            scaleType: 'time',
            data: xAxis,
            valueFormatter: (value: Date, context) =>
              context.location === 'tooltip'
                ? dayjs(value).format('LL')
                : (undefined as unknown as string) // we need to return undefined to use the default formatter
          }
        ]}
        series={[
          {
            highlightScope: { highlighted: 'item' },
            id: 'price',
            area: true,
            color: palette.primary.main,
            type: 'line',
            data: series,
            showMark: false,
            valueFormatter: (value) => (value ? `${value.toFixed(2)} $` : 'N/A')
          }
        ]}
        margin={{ top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20 }}
      >
        <ChartsGrid horizontal />
        <g clipPath={`url(#${clipPathId})`}>
          <LinePlot />
          <AreaPlot />
          <LineHighlightPlot />
        </g>
        <ChartsXAxis />
        <ChartsClipPath id={clipPathId} />
        <ChartsOnAxisClickHandler
          onAxisClick={(_e, d) => {
            if (
              d?.axisValue &&
              dayjs(d.axisValue).diff(date.current, 'days') !== 0
            ) {
              dispatch(updateDate(dayjs(d?.axisValue)?.format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
            }
          }}
        />

        <ChartsAxisHighlight x={'line'} />
        <ChartsReferenceLine
          x={dayjs(date.current).toDate()}
          lineStyle={{
            strokeDasharray: '5 4',
            stroke: palette.primary.dark
          }}
        />
        <ChartsTooltip
          {/* ... probably here there can be some magic */}
        />
      </ResponsiveChartContainer>

I've tried targetting the Tooltip classes, but they are overridden by the <p> element containing the text. I've created a class with makeStyle, and used it for all the available properties of styles in <ChartsTooltip />.
I've tried using the different sx properties of all components, to no effect.
Styling the 'bottom' text (the y axis value) is easy, but the 'top' text in the tooltip is for me impossible.
